# Error from server (BadRequest): container "espace-client-client" in pod "espace-client-client" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, docker-registry, kubernetes-secrets

I've deployed my first app on my Kubernetes prod cluster a month ago.

I could deploy my 2 services (front / back) from gitlab registry.

Now, I pushed a new docker image to gitlab registry and would like to redeploy it in prod:

Here is my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
  labels:
    app: espace-client-client
  name: espace-client-client
  namespace: espace-client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: espace-client-client
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - secretRef:
           name: espace-client-client-env
        image: registry.gitlab.com/xxx/espace_client/client:latest
        name: espace-client-client
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-registry
```

I have no clue what is inside `gitlab-registry`. I didn't do it myself, and the people who did it left the crew :( Nevertheless, I have all the permissions, so, I only need to know what to put in the secret, and maybe delete it and recreate it.

It seems that secret is based on my .docker/config.json

```
➜  espace-client git:(k8s) ✗ kubectl describe secrets gitlab-registry                                                                                
Name:         gitlab-registry
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

Data
====
.dockerconfigjson:  174 bytes
```

I tried to delete existing secret, logout with

```
docker logout registry.gitlab.com
kubectl delete secret gitlab-registry
```

Then login again:

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com -u myGitlabUser
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

and pull image with:

```
docker pull registry.gitlab.com/xxx/espace_client/client:latest
```

which worked.

file: `~/.docker/config.json` is looking weird:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "registry.gitlab.com": {}
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.6 (linux)"
        },
        "credsStore": "secretservice"
}
```

It doesn't seem to contain any credential...

Then I recreate my secret

```
kubectl create secret generic gitlab-registry \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/julien/.docker/config.json \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

I also tried to do :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry gitlab-registry --docker-server=registry.gitlab.com --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

and deploy again:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/espace-client-client -n espace-client
```

but I still have the same error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container "espace-client-client" in pod "espace-client-client-6c8b88f795-wcrlh" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the `gitlab-registry` secret because this item is used to let Kubelet to pull the *protected* image using credentials.

Please, delete the old secret with `kubectl -n yournamespace delete secret gitlab-registry` and recreate it typing credentials:

```
kubectl -n yournamespace create secret docker-registry my-secret --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD[ --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL]
```

where:
- `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER` is the GitLab Docker registry instance
- `DOCKER_USER` is the username of the robot account to pull images
- `DOCKER_PASSWORD` is the password attached to the robot account

You could ignore `docker-email` since it's not mandatory (note the square brackets).

Comment: I updated my answer, just tried this one, but it doesn't work.... still the same error message

Comment: I could fix it, just adding namespace to secret, please add it to your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that could lead to failing image pulls is a deviation in the system time of your machine. This deviation can lead to an error in the tls certificate verification that is performed in image pulls. You can check the current system time: `date`.

A quick fix is to manually set the correct time: `sudo date -s '2023-10-03 12:34:56'`. Alternatively, you can set up [time synchronisation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp).

To check whether this is actually the problem, you can also try to pull images using your container runtime CLI e.g. `crictl pull hello-world`. If this throws an error regarding tls failing to verify the certificate, it is likely that a deviation in system time is the cause.